# Can someone explain the chemistry around adding Isopropyl Alcohol to water contaminated gasoline - how does the IPA 'remove' water from the gas?

Tags: water, alcohols, petrochemistry

So there are many products on the market sold as fuel additives; some (like 'Heet' brand) are nothing more than 99.9% isopropyl alcohol in a nice package.

When trying to understand how they work and what they actually do you hear vague things like "Removes water in fuel. The alcohol will bond with water and solubilize water into gasoline so it can be burned and pass out exhaust"

From what I understand alcohol and water don't 'react' -> there is no chemical formula change. They simply mix really well. But how does this make this new mixture 'mix' with gasoline better?

I know that if you take 50% isopro (other 50% is water) and light it on fire, it will burn. But I understand that it's only the 50% of alcohol molecules burning, not the water. So at the end you'll still end up with the water remaining (excluding some evaporation from the heat).

What's going on? Can someone explain the actual chemistry please of how IPA removes water from the gasoline?

UPDATE: found this technical paper from a chemical engineer on the subject: https://web.archive.org/web/20130427123941/http://www.epa.gov/OMS/regs/fuels/rfg/waterphs.pdf

However, it still doesn't spell out the exact chemistry but should add more context to my question.

Comment: You want the water evenly mixed throughout the gasoline (well, you really want it filtered out). You don't want a blob of water heading into the injectors to be sprayed into a cylinder and not ignite.

Comment: I don't see what "chemistry" you want. Water in fuel is more of engineering issue as Jon says. If you add enough alcohol you get one phase - no separate water phase - no problem. Maybe it's that you reasoned backwards? Alcohol dissolves also in fuel and if you add enough, water has enough solubility in resultant mixture.

Comment: Alcohols are composed by a hydrocarbon chain (R-) and a hydroxyl group (-OH). The bigger the hydrocarbon chain is, the more soluble other organic substances (like fuel) become, but water becomes less soluble. When there is a right balance between R size and OH in terms of total alcohol composition, both substances (fuel and water) become reasonably soluble to form a homogenized mixture. Isopropanol is an example of an alcohol that qualifies.

Comment: Here is a wrong sentence from the second paragraph : *The alcohol will bond with water and solubilize water into gasoline so it can be burned*. This is wrong.  Twice wrong. Alcohol will not solubilize water into gasoline, and water cannot be burned. A mixture $50$% ethanol or isopropanol + $50$% gasoline dissolves less than 1 % water.

Comment: @Maurice I also felt that sentence was wrong and way too vague. So what do you think is going on? Why even bother adding a tiny bottle of alcohol to a gas tank? Is this just snake oil and doesn't do anything meaningful?

Comment: @ wild coast. I have absolutely no idea about the reason of adding some alcohol to a gas tank.

Comment: There is another reason. Nobody wants water to freeze in gas piping or other bottlenecks. Even liquid water may be an obstacle.

Comment: Your paper just says exactly what I did - if you add some alcohol to fuel then water is gonna be a bit more soluble in it. Yeah, it's still less than 1%, but it can be enough to not have another phase - it's not like there's gonna be a glass of water in your tank, but small amount could even condense out of air.

Comment: Related but behind paywall: [Ternary phase diagrams for gasoline-water-alcohol mixtures](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0016236186901924)

Comment: Alcohol in the gasoline will dissolve water and the typical dose is about 250mL. If the amount of water is large it may require repeated dosed to get the engine running right again. We once bought some watered gas in Apalachicola Fl couldn't find any dry gas until Dade City hobbling across the panhandle about 25mph. It took a case of dry gas keeping the fuel level below 1/4 tank to get the car running OK, by that time we were halfway thru Georgia. this was an endemic problem in northern climates almost alleviated by todays gasoline with 10% ethanol. I still have some cans of dry gas, waiting

Comment: HEET used to be 100 % methanol; has it changed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Water separates from gasoline and should not be injected or carbureted in large quantities because it will destabilize engine performance.

Addition of isopropanol in quantities comparable to the water may not make a homogeneous solution in gasoline, but the water-iPA phase will have a surface tension so low (50/50 at 25$^0$ C: 24.26 mN/m vs 21.22 for pure iPA Ref 1)

[image]

that emulsification will be very easy (from shaking due to road conditions like potholes, sharp turns or braking, stopping, etc.).

This sort of behavior is evidenced in practice by formation of a foamy layer between two phases, or just a foamy mass, of tiny separate phase droplets that do not easily recoalesce into two distinct phases. This upsets lab workers who are trying to separate the phases, but the engine is much more tolerant (or could be if the amount of water is not too great).

The engine operates well with injected gasoline; less well with some emulsified water; poorly with too much water in the emulsion. But in general, small amounts of water-containing emulsion can be  injected or carbureted and burned without difficulty.

In other words, the "chemistry" behind the effectiveness of isopropanol's ability to counteract the effect of water in the gas tank does not require a total clarification and transformation into a single phase, but only an assistance so as to be able to minimize the amount of water in each cylinder-load of fuel.

I suppose a surfactant that really emulsified and stabilized a cloudy gasoline-water mixture would burn quite well, even at high concentrations of water.

This is a slightly expanded form of a comment I had posted yesterday.

Ref 1. pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/je00019a016